# Include spell checking in SQL 'LIKE'

Tags: sql, sql-like

I am using sql 'like' to search songs by genre. Like,

```
select * from songs where genre like %hip-hop%
```

and 'hip-hop' will be received by a search bar.

but if the user ACCIDENTLY writes 'jip-jop', that's not going to work for 'hip-hop'. I want it to work even then.
how do i make this happen?

Comment: You should first try something...just a hint: calculating a "distance" from each word/sentence to what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe you should have the users choose from a list of genres rather than typing them in as free text.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I find the question quite clear, although may be a bit broad.

Comment: Which database. In your place a bit more research... I change like -> like-operator , Ok?

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

An SQL implementation is available here http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552

There is also an SQLite function that does that. `editdist3`.

However, you must be careful, because the edit distance from `hip-hop` to `jip-jop` is 2, and the edit distance from `pop` to `rap` is also 2.

Comment: waht happens if i write edit distance 3 instead of 2 in the hip-hop jip-jop example? will it not work?

Comment: typically you will test for a threshold in the edit distance. for example, you can match to anything that has a distance of less than 2. hence the issue I mentioned. a common solution is to normalize by the size of the query or result, and threshold to a percentage